# list contains nonaggregated column

Tags: sql, join, aggregate

I have two tables that look like these:

```
users:
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    primary key(id),
    [...]

product:
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    seller id int unsigned auto_increment,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(seller) references users(id)
    [...]
```

I want to have a list of users with all of their attributes and the amount of products each user has. I tried the following:

```
select u.id, [...], count(p.id) from users u, products p where p.seller=u.id and [...]
```

This, however gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'db.u.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

What would be the proper way of accomplishing the wanted result? And why does this not work?

Comment: Ok, got around my first question relatively quickly by using select id as userid, (select count(id) from products where id=userid) from users . I still don't understand the error.

Comment: Error mentioned a group by. post actual query you have tried

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aggregating data (`count(p.id)`). You are not using `GROUP BY` to get aggregates per some group, so you get only one result row with the aggregates.

But you also select `u.id`. Which one? There are many different `u.id` in the table, but you'll only get one result row. The DBMS expects you to tell it which one you want, e.g. `MAX(u.id)`.

If you want to select user data, select from `users`. If you want to get the number of products, select them in a subquery (which is most easily done in the select clause, but can also be done in the from clause).

```
select
  u.*,
  (select count(*) from product p where p.seller = u.id) as number_of_products
from users u;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get the result you need. Moreover, all the attributes from `user` has to be part of `GROUP BY` clausula.

```
SELECT u.id,  [...], count(p.id) from users u
LEFT JOIN products p where p.seller=u.id
GROUP BY u.id, [...]
```

The error says that you can not mix aggregate functions and attributes behind `SELECT` if you do not have the `GROUP BY` clausula.

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery might be the simplest approach:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*) from products p where p.seller = u.id) as num_products
from users u;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct query you can try:

**ASCII**

```
SELECT u.id, [...], COUNT(p.id) FROM users u JOIN products p ON u.id=p.seller GROUP BY p.seller;
```

**NON-ASCII**

```
SELECT u.id, [...], COUNT(p.id) FROM users u, products p WHERE u.id=p.seller GROUP BY p.seller;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ANY_VALUE` for non aggregated columns. In your example, the non aggregated column was `db.u.id` (see the error message). So, you should use:

```
select ANY_VALUE(u.id), [...], count(p.id) 
from users u, products p 
where p.seller=u.id and [...]
group by [...]
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578865/439171).